# httpclient.execute(httppost) crash in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, http-post, androidhttpclient

I have tried to create a Server Request class for my android application, and it crashes at httpclient.execute(httppost). Even though its inside try/catch, the application is crashing instead of going into the catch section.

code:

```
public static JSONObject ConvertHttpResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ParseException, IOException, JSONException {
    //In: A httpResponse
    //Out: A converted jsonObject from the httpResponse
    HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
    String result=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
    if(jObject.length()==0)
        return null;
    return jObject;
}
  public class DataAsyncSend extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,JSONObject> {
        GetCallback callback;

        public DataAsyncSend(GetCallback callback) {
            this.callback=callback;
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, SERVER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, SERVER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADRESS + pageToSend);
            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
                HttpResponse resposnse= client.execute(post); //crashes here
                return ConvertHttpResponse(resposnse);

            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        callback.done(response);
        super.onPostExecute(response);
    }
```

log:

```
10-21 21:16:45.284: W/EGL_genymotion(2711): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711): org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711):     at Networking.ServerRequests.ConvertHttpResponse(ServerRequests.java:95)
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711):     at Networking.ServerRequests$DataAsyncSend.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:122)
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711):     at Networking.ServerRequests$DataAsyncSend.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:1)
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-21 21:16:45.836: W/System.err(2711):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-21 21:16:45.860: D/AndroidRuntime(2711): Shutting down VM
10-21 21:16:45.860: W/dalvikvm(2711): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa613e908)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at com.example.fififun.User.<init>(User.java:22)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at com.example.fififun.login$2.done(login.java:114)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at Networking.ServerRequests$DataAsyncSend.onPostExecute(ServerRequests.java:133)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at Networking.ServerRequests$DataAsyncSend.onPostExecute(ServerRequests.java:1)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-21 21:16:45.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2711):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

***EDIT:*** The error was that the response was null and it failed parsing the httpRespone into an JSONObject. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post your error log / stack trace.

Comment: Make sure to use the internet permission in the manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: instead of all exceptions ClientProtocolException, IOException ,JSONException etc...

just use the parent class Exception..   catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } 

then the stack will show i hope :)

Comment: @ElliotM Added the log file

Comment: @user3553447 I am using it already

Comment: @Ahmad Added the log file, thank you :)

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject ... clearly the server page is not sending json data and is having issue... try to run the server page in browser also do one thing in the server page write static json like {"data":"this is static json"} then it wont even throw exception...

Comment: @GuyAttali Exception class worked ?

Comment: what is 'data'?
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));